# SQL left join: selecting the last records

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000

I have a table of projects and a table of comments. A project can have many comments. I want to get a list of all projects where the comment postedOn is > 30 days OR projects with no comment. What is the best way to accomplish this?

I’ve had many unsuccessful attempts; this is my latest go at it.

```
SELECT p.id, 
       p.officialStatus, 
       c.posted 
  FROM projects p 
       LEFT JOIN 
       (
        SELECT max(posted) as posted, 
                   projectid 
          FROM comments 
             WHERE DATEDIFF(day, posted, GETDATE()) > 30 
                   OR comment IS NULL
               group by projectid
        ) c ON p.id = c.projectid 
 WHERE (p.officialStatus NOT IN ('Blue', 'Canceled'))
```

Please use these table/column names in your answer:

- projects: id, officialStatus
- comments: id, projectID, postedOn

Comment: I'm wondering, what are criteria of choosing right answer? Were other queries wrong and return invalid data? Or they were also fine, but the choosen one has the best performance? I think answer to this question may be valuable outcome of your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT projects.id FROM projects
  LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT comments.projectID 
       FROM comments
      GROUP BY comments.projectID
      HAVING DATEDIFF(Now(), MAX(comments.postedOn)) < 30) AS C
  ON projects.id = C.projectID
  WHERE C.projectID IS NULL;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ec919/14

Comment: I just discovered sqlfiddle yesterday and I'm in love.

Comment: Thank you for your response Barbara. Sorry, I should have been more clear in my initial question, I'm running MS SQL 2000 and it doesn't recognize 'CURRENT_DATE'. Any suggestion? I agree with Wirus +1 on the sqlfiddle!

Comment: Does it recognize Now()?  How about GetDate()?

Comment: Yes, you beat me to it. I also had to add an additional argument to DATEDIFF(day, MAX(comments.posted), getdate()) for MS SQL. I'm going to validate the data and let you know the outcome. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Thanks again Barbara, the return data checked out. In case anyone is interested here my working query http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/41bf6/1.

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT PROJ.id,
        PROJ.officialStatus
   FROM Projects PROJ
        LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT projectid, MAX(posted) AS max_posted
              FROM Comments 
                   GROUP BY projectid
        )  COMMENTS ON PROJ.id = COMMENTS.projectid
  WHERE PROJ.officilstatus NOT IN ('Blue', 'Cancelled)
        AND COMMENTS.max_posted IS NULL
         OR COMMENTS.max_posted >= DATEADD(day, -30, Now())
```

I think your main problem was the outer join, which was exactly what you didn't need...   In this tweak, projects with no comments will have a NULL max_posted date.

Comment: I'm using a SQL Server function, `DateAdd` which doesn't exist in MySQL or Oracle, but has equivalents on those platforms.   I assumed SQL Server from your use of `DateDiff` in your example query.

Comment: Hi Curt, Thanks for your response. I'll give your query a shoot and will let you know the outcome.

Answer (score 0):

```
select p.*, max(c.postedOn) as postedDate from Projects p
left join Comments c on p.id = c.projectId
group by p.id
having COALESCE( postedDate, DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 31 DAY ) ) < 
    DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 30 DAY );
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ec919/17 - also with execution plan (thanks @Barbara for preparing this test on sqlfiddle)

Comment: Hi Wirus, thank you for your reply. Sorry, I wasn't more clear in my initial question, I'm running MS SQL 2000 and it doesn't recognize 'CURRENT_DATE'. any suggestion?